# Relay / Forward Websocket Traffic in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, websocket

I'm looking for a way to forward websocket traffic that is received by a standard Chrome instance on Windows.

Eg. On a website that establishes a WS session. As the frames come in from the server, I want to relay / forward them to a service on my local network. I'd also want the browser to receive as normal.

Is there a way to do this within Chrome or via an extension? If not, I am assuming best option to to set up a proxy server?

Any other ideas /suggestions appreciated

Thanks